# Why does the Microsoft AES sample return the decrypted data after the using statement

Tags: c#, aes

Looking at that sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

Microsoft returns the decrypted data after the using statement.

Has that a special reason because that sample is using Streaming classes?

Or is that just a quick put together sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a quick put together sample, if they had done `return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();` it would have had the exact same behavior.

They likely split it apart to make it more clear that `ReadToEnd()` is returning a string object that can exist outside of the using scope.